# How to Convert byte to base64 string

Tags: java, string, base64, encode

I retrieve image from db and i want to convert byte to base64 ,

when I use string `s=new string (byte,ascii ) ;` then If i want to `sysout` only the last `byte` converts and prints,

it's list of images need to convert to `base64`  and store in `array` ,and if the method have `sysout` with `"hello"` even that is not printing .

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? your code snippet? output??

Comment: Ex: if i have images to convert from byte to base64 , only 5th image gets base64 ,other then this nothing works

Answer (score 1):

For JDK 6+ there is another way. It's method from JAX-WS specification `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter#printBase64Binary(byte[] array)`. This class is part of rt.jar - runtime library of Java SE

Answer (score 0):

Could you please use following code snippet:

```
byte[] originalBytes = {104, 101,108, 108, 111 };
System.out.println("original: "+new String(originalBytes));
byte[] encodedBytes = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(originalBytes);
System.out.println("encoded: "+new String(encodedBytes));
```

Please note that `Java 8` has been used.

You may use following line if you are not using Java 8 yet. But you need to use the apache library `commons-codec-1.10.jar`

```
byte[] encodedBytes = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(originalBytes);
```